# PHP Could not Select Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting this strange error when I downloaded my files from webserver to my local xampp.

I have `db.php` like this.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{
    session_start();
}
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = $_SESSION['company'];
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysql_error()."Could not connect DATABASE");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die(mysql_error()."Could not select DATABASE");
?>
```

And I have `reference-report.php` like this

```
 <?php 

    include 'db.php';

  ?>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/buttons.css">

<style type="text/css">

img{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
//some other html code.....
```

when I run the file `reference-report.php` I get the output as `Could not select database`

One thing to notice is that in the file `db.php` the die command has `database` written in `uppercase`. and the output shown has `database` written in `lowercase`.

The file `reference-report.php` doesnot contain any mysql connectivity code.
Also there is only one db.php in my website structure. and both the php files are in the same directory.

I am unable to find out why there is this error.

pastebin of `reference-report.php` http://pastebin.com/QbpvMin4

Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

**EDIT:** I tried to set the value of `$mysql_database` manually but still the same problem. the other files dependent on `db.php` work properly except this one.

Also added mysql_error() in die command but the output remains same. maybe `db.php` is not getting included?

**EDIT 2:** Added the contents of `db.php` to `reference-report.php` i.e now it is independent of `db.php`

Now `reference-report.php` looks like this:

```
<?php 

session_start();
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "valid_db_name";
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysql_error()."Could not connect DATABASE");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die(mysql_error()."Could not select DATABASE");

?>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/buttons.css">

<style type="text/css">

img{
//some other html code......
```

The output situation still remains the same. Now this is some good pain in the as*

**SOLUTION** This was like my most frustrating and silliest mistake. the url was `websitename.com/php/filename.` where as it should have been `localhost/php/filename`

Comment: does the same database exist in your local server ?

Comment: Since the output doesn't match what you see in the source code, I suspect you're actually including a different version of `db.php` than the one you're looking at.

Comment: is your $_SESSION['company'] set and it contains any value. move session_start outside of if

Comment: You should include `mysql_error()` in the error message when you call `die()`, so you see the reason for the failure.

Comment: Are you sure about the password? Try adding root as the password as well.

Comment: yes the database does exist @AncientGeek.

Comment: I only have one db.php in my whole website structure i know since i made a search @Barmar

Comment: tried root as password still the same output. also check edit in OP @OsamaYawar

Comment: If you're not getting the output from `db.php`, you must not be running this script. There's no way we can tell from here what's going wrong on your server.

Comment: try changing `include` to `require`

Comment: moved contents from db.php to my php file check edit @Barmar

Comment: @CIRCLE require also doesnt work

Comment: Are you still not getting the output from this `die()`? Are you sure `reference-report.php` is being run? If you put something like `echo "This is reference-report.php"` in it, do you see it?

Comment: Solution found check OP sorry !

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to change `$mysql_database` to the actual name of the database for a quick test.

I'm guessing that the `$_SESSION['company']` is not being set correctly, it's worth checking what is in that and making sure that it is indeed a valid database name.

Comment: I tried to change $mysql_database to a actual value but still the same problem. strange thing is that other php files dependent on db.php work properly except this one.

Comment: try copying and pasting the contents of the `db.php` file into your `reference-report.php` file instead. Just to make sure that is indeed the code that is being run.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pdo:

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "titoni");

try{
    $db = new \PDO(   'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.'; dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, 
                        array(
                            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                            \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
                            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                            \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                        )
                    );

}
catch(\PDOException $ex){
    print($ex->getMessage());
}


?>
```

Comment: Based on his symptoms, he's not even running the script he posted. You're attacking the wrong problem.

Comment: when you tested the pdo example, what was the error it gave you?